# How to find list of groups that are present in '/etc/passwd' but not in the '/etc/group'?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to find list of groups that are present in `/etc/passwd` but not in the  `/etc/group`

I have written the following command so far

```
for user in $(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1); do
    printf "%s: %s\n" $user "$(id -nG $user)"
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ id -Gz | cat -v
197121^@114^@197610^@544^@545^@4^@66049^@11^@15^@113^@4095^@66048^@262154^@405504^@$

$ getent passwd | tr '[:alpha:]' '#'
########:*:197609:197121:#-#######53\########,#-1-5-21-2486228713-2700429697-662227502-1001:/####/########:/###/####
##############:*:544:544:#-#######\##############,#-1-5-32-544:/:/####/#######
######:*:18:18:#-## #########\######,#-1-5-18:/####/######:/###/####
##### #######:*:19:19:#-## #########\##### #######,#-1-5-19:/:/####/#######
####### #######:*:20:20:#-## #########\####### #######,#-1-5-20:/:/####/#######
##############:*:544:544:#-#######\##############,#-1-5-32-544:/:/####/#######
## #######+################:*:328384:328384:#-## #######\################,#-1-5-80-956008885-3418522649-1831038044-1853292631-2271478464:/:/####/#######

$ awk 'NR==FNR{grps[$0];next} !($3 in grps){print $3}' RS='\0' <(id -Gz) RS='\n' FS=':' <(getent passwd)
197609
18
19
20
328384
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, where it will give entries of those group names which are present in `/etc/passwd` and NOT in `/etc/group`.

```
awk -F':' 'FNR==NR{a[$5]=$0;next} ($1 in a){delete a[$1]} END{for(i in a){print a[i]}}' /etc/passwd  /etc/group
```

Answer (score 0):

with `grep/cut`

```
$ grep -vxFf <(cut -d: -f1 </etc/group) <(cut -d: -f1 </etc/passwd)
```

Comment: Yes, x is added now to prevent that.